# Mac is stuck and restart after android studio emulator is turned on

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using a mac book pro with 16GB ram and core i9 processor. computer is working fine and when i start the android studio emulator suddenly internet is getting 100% slow and in few minutes mac is automatically restarting. but in the same computer emulator and android was working perfectly. once i encountered this issue, i completely reset my pc and reinstalled the operating system. however still it remains the same.

Comment: Similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58693637/android-emulator-start-makes-mac-unresponsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was actually happening with the source code with some infinite loops. in a such situation, it's better to check the code properly.