# Android emulator start makes Mac unresponsive

Tags: macos, android-emulator

I'm trying to set up an android emulator on a brand new MacBook Pro (2019 late i7 6-core (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz), Radeon 555x).

When I set up an emulator always happens the same: Emulator starts to boot and mac become unresponsive (trackpad becomes a brick. Then the Mac system restarts with no error report just with "BAD MAGIC! (flag set in iBoot panic header), no macOS panic log available" message.

What I tried: Reinstall HAXM, different versions of HAXM, different versions of the android studio (inc. 4.0.1 canary), different versions of AVD, all above using homebrew, using software graphic, more RAM, and clean iOS reinstall too (with full clear). Genymotion also failed.
On Windows, after a clean install (boot camp) the same happens. ARM-based emulators can start, but they are extremely slow.

I've reset SMC, NVRAM and diagnostics say everything is fine...

All suggestion is appreciated.

Updates:
Current MacOS version: 10.15.3 (19D76)

I also tried backing up the **wrong** mac and restore on another MBP, in this case, it worked on the other MBP.
I tried to remove these folders one by one:

```
• ~/Library/InputMethods
  • ~/Library/InputManagers
  • ~/Library/Caches
  • ~/Library/Containers
  • ~/Library/Application Support
  • ~/Library/Preferences
  • /Library/LaunchAgents
  • /Library/LaunchDaemons
  • /Library/StartupItems
  • /Library/InputMethods
  • /Library/InputManagers
```

- Tried in safe mode,
- with other emulators (genymotion, bluestacks),
- under a virtual machine (VMware and VirtualBox with ubuntu) when
  the emulator starts the same happens.
- tired under Catalina
- Contacted intel, they said: "Apple has explicitly requested all support inquiries or issues to be addressed directly to them"
- Contacted Apple (million times... for 6 months) they said: "Since the problem is caused by a third party application, there is limited protection or support to provide." After using capture data, their engineers have found out that the issue may be caused by "com.intel.haxm" (like I said, surprise!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was clearly CPU related. We've found some similar cases with the same CPU, so the resolution was replacing my MBP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the crash logs (`/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/*.panic`)? If the problem is due to the graphics driver, try using a utility to force your Macbook to use low-powered graphics instead of the AMD card. I personally use [gSwitch](https://github.com/CodySchrank/gSwitch).

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it didn't help. The error logs only referring to HAXM/Intel or to the virtual machine which using it.

Answer (score -1):

check your source code, it might be some background processing and/or infinite loops.